# zip with next value with kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

how to zip a Flow with the next value as zipWithNext operator for collections?

zipWithNext behaves like:

```
val letters = ('a'..'f').toList()
val pairs = letters.zipWithNext()

println(letters) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
println(pairs) // [(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (d, e), (e, f)]
```

but in my case letters would be:

```
val letters = flowOf('a'..'f')
```

bonus points:

i tried `flowOf(1, 2, 3).scan(emptyList<Int>()) { acc, value -> acc + value }.toList()` on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ but doesn't find `flowOf` what import or else i'm missing there?

Comment: Did you imported the [kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flowOf](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-of.html)? A working example: [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-of.html) and btw I don't believe scan will do work for you as you've expected.

Comment: Here's a discussion over that, there's a simple implementation https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1767 you might wanna do that with nulls instead of singletons maybe, to avoid the explicit castings.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

```
val letters = ('a'..'f').toList().toTypedArray()
val lettersFlow = flowOf(*letters)
val result = lettersFlow.scan(Pair<Char, Char>('a','a')) { acc, value -> Pair(acc.second, value) }.drop(2).toList()
println(result)
```